# Is there a way to automate Google Web Optimizer approvals?

Tags: testing, web-applications, automation, google-analytics

Google Web Optimizer uses URLs for its A/B testing experiments. In addition to the production URL, we also have several pre-production environments. Releases of software are pushed out.

We're only running our first experiment now, but we've set up five experiments in GWO -- one for each environment (and thus URL).

It's a bit of a pain to set up all these experiments manually -- especially when verifying the pages.

Is there some kind of API or other automated way to set these up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; as of May 2011, the GWO API above has been discontinued. A future version of the API will supposedly show up, at some point, though - so it may get possible again.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what your after: [Website Optimizer API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gwo/)